# Valid Regex Expression

Tags: regex

okay i have this string

```
String line = "6!.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:05:49 -0800] \"GET      
/twiki/bin/edit/Main/Double_bounce_sender? 
topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariables HTTP/1.1\" 401 12846";
```

i also have this java regular expression

```
Pattern c = Pattern.compile("(\\s+\\/+)(?<=\\/).*(?=)");
```

can anyone help me with a regular expression that will extract this /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Double_bounce_sender?

in the case where there may be question mark at the end or there may be a space without also matching the rest of line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a one liner, you could try using `String.replaceAll`:

```
String match = line.replaceAll(".*\\s+(/[^?\\s]*)(?:\\?|\\s).*", "$1");
```

Comment: i can't directly put GET because it is supposed to math for anycase

Comment: There may be the word POST there or anything else

Comment: i kind of just want it to match this /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Double_bounce_sender? or this /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Double_bounce_sender

Comment: I updated my regex again.  The bottom line is that you are going to need some fixed structure if you want to write a robust regex.

Comment: however i kind of needed this /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Double_bounce_sender(white space or ? can follow this)

Comment: because when i replace the question mark with the space it doesn't find a match

Comment: your most recent edit returns this /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Double_bounce_sender topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariables HTTP/1.1" 401 when i take out the add the space instead of the ?

Comment: i should get this (/twiki/bin/edit/Main/Double_bounce_sender) regardless of what comes after whether it is a space or question mark

Comment: Sorry I had another problem try again.

Comment: oh you want me to try it now?

Comment: `[^?\\s]` this was the problem (it is now fixed as you see it).  Basically, match the URL until you hit the first space or question mark, then stop matching.  Yes, it should work now.

Comment: thanks so much this has been stumping me for hours...you give lessons lol

Comment: just did where can i learn to use regex as effectively as you?

Comment: Honestly, if you want to learn regex, follow Wiktor on SO here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew